# TypeError: fsevents is not a constructor (already tried a bunch of answers)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I'm was following Maximilian Schwarzmüller's react tutorial (udemy) to

```
sudo npm install create-react-app -g
```

then:

```
create-react-app react-complete-guide --scripts-version 1.1.5
```

And it all worked fine (with some warnings, no doubt)

then, i cd into the folder to and `npm start`

**First i got this error:** `sh: react-scripts: command not found`

from a suggestion on this link: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6594

I tried: `PATH=$PATH:./node_modules/.bin npm start`

and it could launch a browser and it worked!!

**BUT HERE's when things started to turn shitty:**

in the thread, the same person suggested: `Install the package in the global npm install -g react-scripts` or `yarn global react-scripts`. Then, it can be executed without setting environment (PATH=$PATH:...).

so i did  `npm install -g react-scripts`

and i started getting error:

```
TypeError: fsevents is not a constructor
```

What I know is this error is supposedly very common. And I've tried all the solutions I came across: install yarn, `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`, then `npx create-react-app my-app`. I also tried

`npm audit fix --force` and `npm i fsevents`

but nothing worked. it still showed me the same `TypeError: fsevents is not a constructor`

I feel like i might have screwed up my terminal. and I probably pulled out half the hair on my head. Please help me ~ i would be really grateful for any advice~ OTL

Comment: have you tried deleting node_modules and installing it again?

Comment: @ImanRb so i move the "node_modules" to trash, and how do i install it again? what command should i use?

Comment: npm i or yarn add

Comment: I just did as you said, and it returned the same error: return (new fsevents(path)).on('fsevent', callback).start();
          ^

TypeError: fsevents is not a constructor :/ any other solutions I should try?

Comment: @ImanRb "npm i" could download packages, although it still ultimately failed with the same error. "yard add" on the other hand threw me this msg right at the start: error Missing list of packages to add to your project.

Comment: create a new blank project using yarn.like this : yarn create react-app my-app

Comment: @ImanRb when i ran your code, it showed: The directory my-app contains files that could conflict:

  node_modules
  package.json
  public
  src
  yarn.lock
and when i ran yarn start, it still showed the fsevents typeerror

Comment: What I meant was if it's not an important project just make a new project in another directory.but this time build it with yarn(yarn create react-app my-app).and then use yarn start to start project.

Comment: @ImanRb I just did.. I made a new directory, yarn create react-app my-app, cd my-app, yarn start, and it still shows the same error :/ any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

For this error

> *TypeError: fsevents is not a constructor*

I had to install watchman on my mac
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/troubleshooting/#npm-test-hangs-or-crashes-on-macos-sierra

```
brew install watchman
```